# Numbering of indices, is $\mathbf b=(b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1})$ a tuple of $n-1$ components?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I have a couple of questions regarding the numbering of indices for vectors.

For a the vector
$
\mathbf a=(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) 
$,
I know this is a tuple of $n$ components.

But if I have
$$
\mathbf b=(b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}) \tag 1
$$
is this a a tuple of $n-1$ components?

And
$$
\mathbf c=(c_2, c_3, \dots, c_{n+1}) \tag 2
$$
is this a a tuple of $n-1$ components?

But if the first index is $1$ and last is $n+1$, i.e.
$$
\mathbf d=(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_{n+1}) \tag 3
$$
is this a a tuple of $n+1$ components?

Or if the first index is $0$ and last is $n+1$, i.e.
$$
\mathbf e=(e_0, e_1, \dots, e_{n+1}) \tag 4
$$
is this a a tuple of $n+2$ components?

And finally, if the first index is $2$ and last is $n$, i.e.
$$
\mathbf f=(f_2, f_3, \dots, f_{n}) \tag 5
$$
is this a a tuple of $n-1$ components?

Comment: Is $(b_0,b_1)$ a tuple of one component?

Comment: The number of components is the number of components. (1) and (2) have $n$; (3) has $n+1$; (4) has $n+2$; (5) has $n-1$. Simples!

Comment: Anything to say, Donsert?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your comment could be an answer, so I'm satisfied. :)

Comment: OK. I'm glad to see you accepted the answer posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of components in $(b_f, b_{f+1}, \dots, b_l)$ is always $l-f+1$  (last $-$ first $+1$). So, (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) have $n,n,n+1,n+2, n-1$ components respectively. Always try things out for small $n$, and check your answers.